# Mysql OPTIMIZE TABLE for all fragmented tables

Tags: mysql, optimization, fragmentation, defragmentation

I'd like to `OPTIMIZE` all currently fragmented tables. These tables should have `information_schema.DATA_FREE > 0`.

Is it possible to optimize all tables with this property in one command in SQL or will I have to write external code to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT concat("OPTIMIZE TABLE ", table_schema,".",table_name,";")
FROM tables
WHERE DATA_FREE > 0
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/optimize.sql';
SOURCE '/tmp/optimize.sql';
```

Alternatively, if the first one fails, try:

```
SELECT concat("OPTIMIZE TABLE ", table_schema,".",table_name,";")
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE DATA_FREE > 0
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/optimize.sql';
SOURCE /tmp/optimize.sql;
```

Comment: Slight changes required to work for me, but great approach.

SELECT concat("OPTIMIZE TABLE ", table_schema,".",table_name,";") FROM information_schema.tables WHERE DATA_FREE > 0 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/optimize.sql'; SOURCE /tmp/optimize.sql;

Comment: You need some backticks cat-ed in there around table_schema and table_name, otherwise i owe you a beer, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is an old post, but this is needed.

Phil Dufault http://www.dufault.info/blog/a-script-to-optimize-fragmented-tables-in-mysql/
has written a wonderfull script, that is on github:
https://github.com/pdufault/mysqlfragfinder/blob/master/mysqlfragfinder.sh

```
vim mysqlfragfinder.sh
#copy paste from github
chmod +x ./mysqlfragfinder.sh
./mysqlfragfinder.sh --user root_username --password root_password
```

and that is all. 
Have been using it on a number of servers for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a answer.  But MySQL has this recommendation for INNODB DB's:

> It can speed up index scans if you periodically perform a “null” ALTER
>   TABLE operation, which causes MySQL to rebuild the table:
>
> `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=INNODB`

Found here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html